# Kafka-Broker not available after some time of message transfer

Tags: apache-kafka

Connection to node 1 could not be established after _consumer_offset-49,
I am not able to solve the issue,till _consumer_offset-49 consumer is able to get message but after offset-49 , it show WARNING message i.e Connection to node 1 could not be established,broker not may not be available.

```
C:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0>.\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test1
>hi
>hello
>hey
>whatsupp??
>how are u
>[2019-02-25 03:53:14,876] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-02-25 03:53:15,982] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-02-25 03:53:17,240] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I just changed the Java version to Java-1.8-181 and it worked.